# 7 if else queries in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I am using the IMPORTXML function to grab some data about opening hours for a local store. Column A contains the 7 days of the weeks and column B contains the opening hours.

What I am looking to do is an if/else query so in cell C1, I have =today(). So, in Cell D1, I want to compare the values in column A (days of the week) and if it matches the value of TODAY (C1) (ie. it's the same day), I would then like to extract the respective value from column B (the opening hour).

So, in cell D1, this will hold the function and will always display the relevant opening hours depending on the day of the week matching TODAY (cell C1).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Something like `=vlookup(Weekday(C1), A:B, 2, false)` should do the trick. Assuming that the `Weekday()` function returns the same numbered weekday as your Column `A`. You may need to tweak that like `=vlookup(Weekday(C1)-1, A:B, 2, false)`. Impossible to say though without seeing your data. [See here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en) for more info on the `vlookup()` formula in google sheets.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming B1:B7 contains the opening times for `Sunday` to `Monday` in that order, then perhaps:

```
=index(B:B,weekday(C1))
```